# On new node create , Drupal is giving error message "The file used in the Image field may not be referenced."

Tags: drupal-7

When I am gong to create a new node of a type , then upload the image field , its showing an error "The file used in the Image field may not be referenced.". I have implemented the hook_file_insert function in which it was told to use file_usage_add. I have my code below:

```
function mymodule_file_insert($file){

  if($file->source=="field_image_und_0" || $file->source=="field_twitter_image_und_0"){
    mymodule_manage_file($file);
  }
}




/**
 * implements file manage
 */
function mymodule_manage_file($file){
  if($file->fid){
    mymodule_save_file($file->fid);
  }
}

/**
 * implements save file
 */
function mymodule_save_file($file_id){


  $file = file_load($file_id);
  $file->status = FILE_STATUS_PERMANENT;
  file_save($file);
  file_usage_add($file, 'file', 'node', $nid);

}
```

Here I get here the nid when new node is creating?

Answer (score 1):

Your are passing the $nid, and it has not value. I think this should works:

```
function mymodule_file_insert($file){

    if($file->source=="field_image_und_0" || $file->source=="field_twitter_image_und_0"){
        mymodule_manage_file($file);
    }
}

/**
 * implements file manage
 */
function mymodule_manage_file($file){
    if($file->fid){
        mymodule_save_file($file->fid);
    }
}
/**
 * implements save file
 */
function mymodule_save_file($file_id, $nid){

    $file = file_load($file_id);

    if (isset($nid)) {
        file_usage_add($file, 'file', 'node', $nid);
    }else {
        $file->status = FILE_STATUS_PERMANENT;
        file_save($file);

    }

}

/**
 * Implements hook_node_insert().
*/

function mymodule_node_insert($node) {
    mymodule_save_file($node->field_name[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['fid'], 
   $node->nid);
}
```

Comment: Yah I just give it because the file_usage_add is taking id , and it has be nid for a node, but can I get the nid for a newly creating node as mymodule_save_file will trigger before node_save .

Comment: I added an example for you with the nid.